# What does it means that the result of an ADD instruction "wraps around" if larger than the size of the arguments

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm following Udemy's *Assembly Language Adventures: Complete Course*.

When explaining the ADD instructions, the instructor says that *the result of an ADD instruction "wraps around" if larger than the size of the arguments.*

What does it means that it wraps around?

From my understading, in 4 bits signed I can't add two (positive) numbers that result in a number greater than 7, or the result overflows changing the sign bit. Is it what the instructor means?

Comment: think modulo, as answered below, short form, it clips the lower bits off.  add 0xFF and 0xFF unsigned you get 0x1FE if allowed an unlimited number of result bits, but if limited to 8 in and 8 out the result is FE which is the modulo of the result 2^8 or 256.  you clip off the lower 8 bits of the result kind of like a modulo.  A modulo is how much it wraps around if limited to 8 bits and you wanted to count to 0x1FE or 510.   510/256 is 1 remainder 254 (0xFE).   the signed and unsigned overflow flags further help see if it doesnt fit in the result (carry = unsigned overflow)

Comment: think decimal,  99+99 = 198, but as with computers if I limit myself to two digits the result is 98 it went 98 past the rollover point of 100/zero.

Answer (score 3):

That's essentially it. If you add two numbers such that the result cannot be stored in the destination then:

- carry will be set exactly if there was carry out of the most significant stored column*; and
- overflow will be set exactly if the result has an incorrect sign**.

So, generally, carry is used for extending addition across multiple words, but overflow is the thing to watch to check for an incorrect result if dealing with signed numbers.

By wrapping around, I think he means what you say: if you were dealing with 4-bit unsigned numbers then e.g. 1001 + 1001 = 1 0010 = carry set, result 0010. So you've added 9 to 9 and got a result of 2. The result has in a sense gone all the way up to 15, then wrapped around to 0, then continued on again to 2.

If you instead imagine you were dealing with signed numbers then you actually performed (-7) + (-7) and got a result of 2. You can't get a positive result from adding two negative numbers so overflow is set — the sign is incorrect. And you've wrapped around by going down to -8, then jumping up to 7, then continuing down to 2.

---

* e.g. as though it were any other long addition:

```
1100 +
0101
----
0101 (result)
11   (carry)
```

The most significant column, on the left, produces carry. So the processor would set the carry flag.

** The logic here is really easy:

- if adding two positive numbers produces a negative number, set overflow;
- if adding two negative numbers produces a positive number, set overflow;
- otherwise, reset overflow.

So you just look at the signs of the two numbers. If the signs are the same, but the sign of the result is different, set overflow. Otherwise reset it.

There is no combination of positive and negative number which, when added, will not fit into the destination, even when adding with carry. Try it out with the most extreme examples:

- 127 + (-128) = -1, which fits
- 127 + (anything closer to 0 than -128) = something between -1 and 127, which fits
- (anything closer to 0 than 127) + (-128) = something between -1 and 128, which fits

Comment: While I understood the second part I'm lost at your two bullet points:

What does it means that *carry will be set exactly if there was carry from the most significand stored column to the first implicity lost?*

*overflow will be set exactly if the effect of truncating the result is to give the impression of an incorrect sign.*

What does it means to "set exactly"?

Also, if I add two overflowing numbers in al, is the the result going to "overflow" in ah part of the register?

Comment: Oh, those are just the tests the CPU applies to decide how to set its status bits. I'll try to expand.

Comment: Oh 'set exactly when' is a bit of a lawyerism:  if I just said 'set when' then there could be other reasons why carry might be set. But in this case there aren't. Like if I said "my window will be shut if I am cold"; it could also be shut even though I am warm, but am not home. If I said "exactly if I am cold" then I have promised that if you see that it is shut then, wherever I am, I am cold. If it is not shut then, wherever I am, I am not cold.

Comment: Aquazi: if you `add al,<8 bit value>` and result doesn't fit into 8 bits, `ah` is NOT affected, because only `al` was specified in instruction. To get the overflown value into `ah` you would need to explicitly convert the right side 8 bit value into 16 bit value, `al` into `ax` (8 -> 16b again), and do `add ax,<8 bit value extended to 16 bits>`, that will make `ah` to contain the upper 8 bits of result (with unsigned math after adding two 8 bit values the result will always fit into 9 bits, so ah = 0 or 1 (same as carry in case of `add al,...`). Two signed 8 bit values will end with ah=0 or -1

Comment: @Aquazi when in doubt, run some debugger, open any executable and most of debuggers allow to write few instructions directly in them, so write few `mov` to set up registers to test values, and then put there instruction which you have doubts about, and single step over it. Like `mov al,0C4h` `add al,al` -> `al` will be `0x88`, CF=1, OF=0, ZF=0, SF=1, `ah` unchanged, etc..